# SED Error: sed -i expression

Tags: linux, sed

i execute this command:

```
sed -i 13s/log4j.appender.ROOT2.File=.*/log4j.appender.ROOT2.File='/appli/diap/log.log/' /applis/DIAPASON/diapason1/conf/log4j.properties
```

i have this error:

```
sed: -e expression n°1, caractère 61: option inconnue pour `s'
```

Thx.

Comment: try `sed -i '13s#log4j.appender.ROOT2.File=.*#log4j.appender.ROOT2.File='/appli/diap/log.log/#'' /applis/DIAPASON/diapason1/conf/log4j.properties I.e. use a different delimiter, in this case a `#` instead of a `/` I believe that confuses sed
`

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use a different separator for the `s` expression, or else back-tick the `/` in the path that you're using in the replacement.

e.g.

```
sed -i '13s@\(log4j.appender.ROOT2.File=\).*@\1/appli/diap/log.log@' /applis/DIAPASON/diapason1/conf/log4j.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to backslash the slashes, or use a different separator. Otherwise, the `s///` expression ends before the `appli`, which is an "unknown option for s".

```
sed -i 13s/log4j.appender.ROOT2.File=.*/log4j.appender.ROOT2.File='\/appli\/diap\/log.log/' /applis/DIAPASON/diapason1/conf/log4j.properties
sed -i 13s%log4j.appender.ROOT2.File=.*%log4j.appender.ROOT2.File='/appli/diap/log.log%'    /applis/DIAPASON/diapason1/conf/log4j.properties
```